# pandas pivot table with same rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a data frame. I would like to create a pivot table from this dataframe with both the rows and the columns of the pivot table equal to `df['event']`.

```
In [7]:

df
Out[7]:
event   event_time  num session_id
0   dog     1   2   a
1   cat     2   3   a
2   bird    3   5   a
3   tree    4   7   a
4   cat     1   3   b
5   dog     2   2   b
6   tree    1   7   c
7   dog     2   2   c
8   cat     3   3   c
```

Using:

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(df, 'num', rows='event', cols='event', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: Grouper for 'event' not 1-dimensional`

I would like to get something like (the agg function is arbitrary. I am concerned with the grouping):

```
    bird    cat dog tree
dog     29  13  3   43
cat     31  17  5   47
bird    37  19  7   53
tree    41  23  11  59
```

(numbers are just arbitrary primes.)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Joe, I'm struggling to figure why you would want to do this.  Those relationships in your desired result don't exist in your original df. If I'm missing the point, please disregard my comment.

Comment: Hey Bob. I would like to take each 1:1 permutation of events and assign a unique prime to it. Thought I could do this with pivots. I already have a function that creates primes. I would like the output in a dataframe like I tried to do in my example

Comment: I see...  What about this?    pd.merge(df,df,left_index=True, right_index=True,how='outer').pivot_table('num_x',index='event_x',columns='event_y').  This may not be feasible with large dfs

Comment: I am very interested on this, did you do it?