# Pivot on single column, but with diagonal historic customer visit view

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

With data that is reflected as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CustID': [1,2,3, 2,4,5,1, 6,5,2,7,3,8,9,5,4], 'YearVisited': [2013,2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020,  2020, 2020, 2020,2020]})
sorted_df = df.sort_values(['YearVisited','CustID'], ascending=[True, True])
sorted_df
```

A) I've been unable to get the following view:

| Yr | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2013** | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| **2014** | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| **2015** | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| **2016** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **2017** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **2018** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **2019** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| **2020** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 |

Whereby, the diagonal reflects the total customers for each given year. But the returning customers show above that total against the row where they first visited.

By explanation:

```
in 2014, we had 2 customers, 1 of whom was a returning one from 2013
in 2015 only new customers visited, no returning from previous years
in 2019 3 customers, 2 were returning 1x2013, 1x2018
in 2020 we had 7 customers, 4 were returning, 1x2013, 1x2014, 1x2015, 1x2018
```

These are looking as near my aim as ive seen, but i've struggled to apply it to my own:
i) [pivot a dataframe by diagonals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885197/pivot-a-dataframe-by-diagonals)
ii) [pandas pivot table with same rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193165/pandas-pivot-table-with-same-rows-and-columns)

I've attempted with variations on this, but it's clearly not what i actually need:

```
df['YearVisitedCopy'] = df['YearVisited']
result = (df.assign(count=df.groupby("YearVisited").cumcount())
            .pivot(index='YearVisited', columns='count'))

result.columns = ["_".join(str(x) for x in i) for i in result.columns]

print (result)
```

Update/Additional info:

- Running on 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  (Thank you to Alex for improving the formatting in my question. I'll take note for future. )
- Not a big row count@ ~1035431, optimization not a priority.
- Additional library use is fine. E.g solutions with numpy etc

**- If easier to achieve, the diagonal to be just those new customers for that year rather than the total including the pre**vious years would also be fine, I'd just as happy with totals omitted or appearing elsewhere E.g B.**
B)**

| Yr | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2013** | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| **2014** | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| **2015** | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| **2016** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **2017** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **2018** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **2019** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| **2020** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| **Totals** | **2** | **2** | **1** | **0** | **0** | **1** | **3** | **7** |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still kind of messy but here's a solution to your problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cust_ids = [1,2,3, 2,4,5,1, 6,5,2,7,3,8,9,5,4]
years = [2013,2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020,  2020, 2020, 2020,2020]

min_year, max_year = min(years), max(years)
n_years = max_year - min_year + 1
year_matrix = np.zeros((n_years, n_years), dtype=int)

first_year = {}
for c, y in zip(cust_ids, years):
    year_matrix[min(y, first_year.setdefault(c, y)) - min_year, y - min_year] += 1

totals = year_matrix.sum(axis=0)
```

**solution B)**

```py
df_b = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((year_matrix, totals)), columns=range(min_year, max_year + 1), index=list(range(min_year, max_year + 1)) + ['total'])
print(df_b)
```

```py
       2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
2013      2     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
2014      0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
2015      0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
2016      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2017      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2018      0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
2019      0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
2020      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
total     2     2     1     0     0     1     3     7
```

**solution A)**

```py
np.fill_diagonal(year_matrix, totals)
df_a = pd.DataFrame(year_matrix, columns=range(min_year, max_year + 1), index=range(min_year, max_year + 1))
print(df_a)
```

```py
      2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
2013     2     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
2014     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     1
2015     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
2016     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2017     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2018     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
2019     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     0
2020     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     7
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Really appreciated. That has indeed got it. Actually not as 'messy' as i was expecting :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. First we calculate (B):

```py
sorted_df['first_visit'] = sorted_df.groupby('CustID').transform('min')

years = range(2013, 2021)
new_customers = sorted_df.pivot_table(index='first_visit', columns='YearVisited', values='CustID', aggfunc='count') \
  .reindex(columns=years, index=years).fillna(0)
```

New customers:

```
YearVisited  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
first_visit                                                
2013          2.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0
2014          0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
2015          0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
2016          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2017          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2018          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
2019          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
2020          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   3.0
```

Then we can use the combine() function to fill in the max values from the year's totals:

```py
import numpy as np

result = sorted_df.pivot_table(index='YearVisited', columns='YearVisited', values='CustID', aggfunc='count') \
  .reindex(columns=years, index=years) \
  .fillna(0) \
  .combine(new_customers, np.maximum)
```

Result:

```
YearVisited  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
YearVisited                                                
2013          2.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0
2014          0.0   2.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
2015          0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
2016          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2017          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2018          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
2019          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   3.0   0.0
2020          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   7.0
```